# Identity element in a commutative rng.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules

Let me start with a construction. Take a commutative rng $A$ and for every finitely generated $A$-module $M$ take the endomorphism ring $\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ which is itself a ring with identity. Let the rng homomorphism $h_M: A\to\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ defined by mapping $a\in A$ to the map $m\mapsto am$. Now by the fact that $M$ is finitely generated over $A$ we must have some $a\in A$, $h_M(a)$ maps to the identity map in $\mathrm{End}_A(M)$.(To see this, apply Cayley-Hamilton for the identity map in $\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ to obtain an element $a\in A$ such that $am=m$ for all $m\in M$.) Thus the image $h_M(A)$ is a commutative ring with identity(It is commutative since it only contains left multiplications by elements in $A$.) Note that $h_M$ is injective if and only if $M$ is faithful. Thus

> A commutative rng $A$ is a ring if and only if there exists a finitely generated faithful module acting on $A$.

There are quite a lot questions I came up with when trying to get some insight into this construction. So I guess the best answer should be a reference book/article on this subject, but let me write some of my questions down:

1. How canonical is $h_M$ for each finitely generated module $M$? Given another finitely generated module $N$ over $A$ is there a unique automorphism $f\in\mathrm{Aut}_A(M)$ such that $h_N=fh_M$?
2. How does informations for the map $h_M$ for each finitely generated module $M$ over $A$ tell us about the "obstruction" for adding an identity to the ring $A$? This question might be a little vague, but I should be looking for a "homological" answer.
3. What are the maps $h_M\in\mathrm{End}_A{M}$ for finitely generated module $M$ over $A$ tell us about the ring $A$?

Again the best answer I would wish to get should be a reference that includes this subject to study. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand how you're deducing that some $a\in A$ must map to the identity.  What if, say, $M$ is some arbitrary finitely generated abelian group and $A$ acts on it by $0$?

Comment: Oh, I guess maybe you are using "finitely generated" in a nonstandard way, to mean that there is a finite collection of elements such that the induced map $A^n\to M$ is surjective.  That's not the same as the usual meaning of finitely generated for modules over rngs!

Comment: In general $\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ is not commutative.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes I am using the definition that a finite set of elements in $M$ generates $A$. But I am curious now how one defines it using the standard way. I think wikipedia uses the "nonstandard" way though..

Comment: @Mohan Oh yes sorry I mean that the subring of "constants" of it is commutative. I will fix it.

Comment: The standard definition is that a subset $S$ of a module $M$ generates $M$ if no proper submodule of $M$ contains $S$, and $M$ is finitely generated if it is generated by a finite subset.  Concretely, this means we can build every element of $M$ from $S$ using the module operations, but we are _not_ required to multiply each element of $S$ by a scalar when doing so.